# Mouse coordinates over HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, three.js

i am trying to use an example from the three.js page's, the voxel painter one. In this example the mouse coordinates's are used to move a roll-over helper that indicates the position where a box will be placed after the click.

```
mouse.set((event.clientX/window.innerWidth)*2-1, -(event.clientY/window.innerHeight)*2+1);
```

This piece of code calculates the position of the mouse all over the page.
I have added other div elements in the page such that the total amount of space for the webGL canvas is different from the total amount of space in the page, the new dimensions of the webGL canvas are 95% of the total height and 85% of the total width.

Now, the mouse position's over my webGL canavas is obviously different therefore the roll-over helper does not overlap anymore the position of the mouse. How have i to modify the above piece of code?

Comment: It looks like on their example page all of the examples are wrapped in an iframe so the window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight refers to the height and width of the iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use jQuery to detect mouse position which works off any jQuery object passed to it.

```
$(function() {
  var xCoord, yCoord;
  $(document).on("mousemove", function(event) {
    xCoord = event.pageX;
    yCoord = event.pageY;
    console.log("x: "+ xCoord+ ", y: "+ yCoord);
  } );
} );
```

Just change the jQuery selector to your canvas and jQuery will handle the rest.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Tip: stop using jQuery.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! The coordinates of the mouse are relative to the whole page and not only to the div element that i want.

Comment: you are using a canvas for displaying stuff that triggers the mouse over correct? The example I gave you references the whole doc, yes. However, you can change the reference object to you're div or canvas or whatever it is that's displaying your info. You could even bring it one step farther through CSS styling and set its position to relative making the top left corner of the obj (0, 0) and the event.pageX/Y will return those coords respective to that corner.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the global position of the mouse cursor on your page, you should rather use the page coordinates like this:

```
event.pageX
event.pageY
```